# Provide multiple thumb-drives via RAID 0 / USB-hub better performance than a single thumb-drive?

Tags: usb, performance, usb-flash-drive, usb-storage

Suppose I'd attach **N flash-sticks to an USB-hub** and configure them using soft-**RAID level 0** [striping].

Is this configuration likely to provide better throughput than a single flash-stick?

Answer (score 0):

My guess (if it was even possible) is that it would be slower. The OS (or whatever) is doing the striping would need to break a single write into multiple ones. Because of communication overhead and the hub design of USB I think it would be slower.